# how to make Landing page URL user friendly or readable?

Tags: marketing-cloud, url, landing-page

I have created a landing page in Salesforce Marketing cloud Cloudpages and would like to have a friendly URL e.g. abc.com/signup for the same. Please suggest.

URL for the landing page is https://pub.s10.exacttarget.com/xpy3js1gpzi

I have gone thru the below help URLs and unable to proceed:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_create_a_friendly_url_in_a_cloudpages_landing_page.htm&type=5

What I feel is that I need SF to activate something in order to perform this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I recommend **speaking to your AE** to figure it out
I had raised a case with SF and found out that we need to buy the required domain or allow SF to buy it.
After that we need to configure the CNAME on our domain and rest is done by SF.
Ones the above step are finished, we can use these customized URLs for our landing pages.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have a custom URL apart from ExactTarget you need to buy a private domain or enable Sender Authentication Package(For Professional and Enterprise version). More more details you may refer to this https://partnersolutions.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#1N000002LpRp/a/1N0000005g0n/6eQInn_UFVxljqcbiF9TZwI4LeBpLsQEEAmGzSJoBv0

Comment: Hi Biplab, Salesforce mentions about friendly URL without any purchase. I was looking for that solution.https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_friendly_url_landing_page.htm&type=5

Comment: @Pankaj - you are referring to documentation for classic content. Cloud pages use a different approach: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_personalized_urls.htm&type=5

Comment: @LukasLunow as per your documentation link, it seems that it is available out of the box. I checked this help page and it wasn't helping me. I am thinking  that this help page assumes that you have bought the private domain     
 https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cp_create_a_friendly_url_in_a_cloudpages_landing_page.htm&type=5